# Knockout Custom Bindings Not Called

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following implementation:

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "jqueryMobile"], function ($, ko) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.jqmRefreshList = {

        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {

            alert('I am fired!');

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).listview("refresh");
        }
    };

})
```

And I use it like this:

```
  <div data-bind="foreach :lineItems , jqmRefreshList :true">
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that even though lineItems contains 10-15 entries the "Hello World" div is only printed once. I checked the jqmRefreshList custom binding and the init and the update function is never fired. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a fiddle at jsfiddle.net, or does it work there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your custom binding registering script is not called and there is an error in console, something like `jqmRefreshList` is undefined. See this simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/z562ju74/) without `define`, works as expected. Make sure that your script with `define` is included in right place.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to pass the viewModel to the custom bindings instead of created the viewModel inside the custom bindings.

Comment: Uhmm.. I don't think I understood the question. You pass your view model's property in markup using `data-bind` attribute (instead of `true` in your example).

Comment: Yes, when I pass lineItems instead of the true where can I access that inside the jqmRefreshList.

Comment: You should use `valueAccessor` for this: `var lineItems = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());`.